# Customized HTML patterns

Tags: html, regex, input

I have some input text HTML objects and I want to use patterns for some of them but I don"t know how to make them, it is very difficult

- I would like a pattern that only accepts letters but not numbers and not letters and numbers together
- A pattern that only accepts letters and a dot like firstname.name
- A pattern that only accepts numbers and ( )

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
<input pattern="[A-Za-z]"> //only Letters
</input>
<input pattern="[A-Za-z.]"> //only Letters and dot
</input>
<input pattern="[0-9()]"> //only Numbers and ()
</input>
```

Also please do better research before posting a question.
[On this Site](https://html.com/attributes/input-pattern/) [or this one](https://www.html5pattern.com/Names) its explained/shown rather understandable in my opinion and the site was not hard to find either.